# How do I find the EdgeMartData component a custom field is used in?

Tags: custom-field, dataflow

I am reviewing where a custom field is used and there are two entries for EdgeMartData, with ID links provided (e.g. 0Fc0J0000028itsXXX).  When I click on the hyperlink I get an insufficient privileges.  I assume it's related to some dataflow, but how do I find out exactly which dataflow is using this field?

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar issue previously and had extensive discussions with Salesforce support to address it. When we check on the Field’s references in the “Where is this used” tab you can see EdgeMartData references. But unfortunately, when you click on EdgeMartData ID or search for the dataset by putting the EdgeMartData ID in the URL we cannot find any. As EdgeMartData or EdgeMart are read-only objects only Salesforce Support Team can query them using internal tools and tell you about the related datasets (as I was told). I recommend reaching out to Salesforce support for further assistance.